# chrome extension fire alarm every day using chrome alarm api

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have created reminder app which allows user to create , edit and delete reminder ,  for notification i have used [chrome alarms api](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/alarms) but it's not allowing me to set alarm which fire every day , how can i resolve this ?

here is my code of **controller.js**

```
 var tstamp = App.Util.GetTimeStamp("2015-08-19T12:57");
 var alarmId = "ALM" + Date().getTime();
 chrome.alarms.create(alarmId, {when: tstamp});

 App.Util.GetTimeStamp = function(datetime)
 {
   if(datetime == ""){return new Date().getTime();}

   var date = new Date(datetime);
   return date.getTime() + date.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000;
 }
```

and here **background.js**

```
 chrome.alarms.onAlarm.addListener(function(alm)
 {
   console.log(alm.name);
   ProcessAlarm(alm.name);
 });
```

and it works fine for current date which i have passed but i want this alarm to run everyday.

Comment: What error is displayed in the console? What happens? Please edit your question and add this information and the relevant code.

Comment: @wOxxOm alarm is not fired so it doesn't give me error in console. alarm fired procedure is done by chrome alarm listener though let me give you code of my controller.js and background.js

Comment: 1. Add `App.Util.GetTimeStamp` code. 2. automatically recurring alarms are set via `periodInMinutes`, but as you're using `when` does your code recreate the alarm every time it fires?